# Combinations for every x and y items in Spinners Android

Tags: android, combinations

I have 2 spinners whose items are dynamic i.e, there can be 'n' number of items in both the spinners. I want the possible combinations of every items from both the spinners.

Suppose there are a1,a2 items in Spinner1 and b1,b2,b3 items in Spinner2 then I want combination of item a1 and a2 from spinner1 with all the items of spinner2 i.e, a1b1, a1b2, a1b3 and a2b1,a2b2,a2b3. How can I achieve that?

Comment: a1b1 in what format? string concat of both?

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not understand your question? You know how to populate a Spinner with Data? You know how to get the selected items from a Spinner? What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your first Spinner1 data in list1.

```
List<String> spinner1 = new ArrayList<String>();
spinner1.add(a1);
spinner1.add(a2);
```

And spinner2 data in list2.

```
List<String> spinner2 = new ArrayList<String>();
spinner2.add(b1);
spinner2.add(b2);
spinner2.add(b3);

List<String> finalData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now your final spinner data,

```
for(String s1 : spinner1){
     for(String s2 : spinner2){
     String str = s1.concat(s2);
     finalData.add(str);
    }
}
```